# Vaadin - QR code: Widgetset 'com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet' does not contain implementation

Tags: java, vaadin

Eclipse Neon, Vaadin version 7.3.6. Java 1.8.

I want to show QR code on page , created by Vaadin. So I add dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
        <artifactId>qrcode</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my code in Vaadin I use this:

```
QRCode code = new QRCode();
    code.setValue("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
    code.setWidth("400px");
    code.setHeight("400px");
    addComponent(code);
```

It's compile and run success. But when I try to load html page with QR code I get the next error:

Widgetset 'com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet' does not contain implementation for fi.jasoft.qrcode.QRCode.
Check its component connector's @Connect mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file and re-compile your widgetset.
In case you have downloaded a vaadin add-on package, you might want to refer to add-on instructions.

What is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You need to compile a custom WidgetSet to get this to work. You will find this much easier if you try using Vaadin 7.7.6 (the latest version)

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-compile the widgetset for your application. Actually there is a maven plugin for that. You can find the detailed instructions how to create&comiple custom wigetset here:

https://vaadin.com/directory/help/using-vaadin-add-ons/maven

It's a bit tricky to set everything up, but once it's done, it's only about running

```
mvn vaadin:update-widgetset install
```

You'll have to add some plugins to the pom.xml in order to make this work, the best way how to find out how to add the plugin is to generate the official archetype for the Vaadin application and copy&paste the plugin info from there:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-clean \
-DarchetypeVersion=LATEST \
-DgroupId=your.company \
-DartifactId=project-name \
-Dversion=1.0 \
-Dpackaging=war
```

Note that if you are using spring-boot then there'll be no web.xml where to define the widgetset, but you can actually follow info from this forum: 
https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/9587133